# Exception caught by widgets library on Product Review Section

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Flutter e-commerce app is throwing exceptions on product review screen.

Reference SS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe6RZ.jpg)

[review.dart](https://github.com/anshbot/FlutterWoo/blob/master/review.dart)

Answer (score 0):

The Row is receiving a null widget in its list of children.

One way to avoid `Row` from having null children is to just filter out the null widgets this way:

````dart
Row(
  ...,
  children: <Widget>[
    ...
  ].where((widget) => widget != null).toList()
)```
````